# How to draw a contour of a FirebaseVisionFace imagine created with a Bitmap?

Tags: java, android, firebase, machine-learning, firebase-mlkit

Im making a face contour detector using Firebase ML Kit. 
I created a FirebaseVisionImage object using the fromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) method and a FirebaseVisionFaceDetector with certain options. 
The question is: is there any class that will help me draw a contour around the face that my app already detects?

What already works:

- The app already detects the face and its smiling probability, right and left eye open probability......

What I created:

- A class that returns me a List of points of, for example, an eye.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
private ImageView pictureImageView;
private ImageButton takePictureButton, choosePictureButton;


private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_READ = 42;


private FirebaseVisionImage faceImage;

private FirebaseVisionFaceDetector faceDetector;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pictureImageView = findViewById(R.id.picture_image_view);
    takePictureButton = findViewById(R.id.take_photo_image_view);
    choosePictureButton = findViewById(R.id.choose_photo_image_view);
}


public void takePicture(View v){
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}


public void choosePicture(View v){
    Intent choosePictureIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).setType("image/*");

    if(choosePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
        startActivityForResult(choosePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_READ);
    }
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

        try { detectFace(bitmap); }
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}

private void detectFace(final Bitmap bitmap) throws Exception {
    FaceUtils faceUtils = new FaceUtils();

    FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions options = faceUtils.getFaceDetectorOptions();

    faceImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap);

    faceDetector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionFaceDetector(options);

    faceDetector.detectInImage(faceImage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<FirebaseVisionFace>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<FirebaseVisionFace> firebaseVisionFaces) {
            if(firebaseVisionFaces.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nessuna faccia trovata", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                String resultText = " ";
                int i = 1;

                for (FirebaseVisionFace face : firebaseVisionFaces) {
                    resultText = "\n" + i + " faccia trovata.\n" + "Sorriso: "
                                    + faceUtils.getSmilingProbability(face) * 100 + "%\nOcchio sinistro: "
                                        + faceUtils.getLeftEyeOpenProbability(face) * 100 + "%\nOcchio destro: "
                                            + faceUtils.getRightEyeOpenProbability(face) * 100 + "%";

                    i++;
                }

                pictureImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString(BundleTags.REQUEST_TEXT, resultText);

                DialogFragment resultDialog = new ResultDialog();
                resultDialog.setArguments(bundle);
                resultDialog.setCancelable(false);
                resultDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), BundleTags.REQUEST_DIALOG);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

**FaceUtils**

```
public FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions getFaceDetectorOptions(){
    FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions options = new FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
            .setPerformanceMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ACCURATE)
            .setContourMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_CONTOURS)
            .enableTracking()
            .setLandmarkMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_LANDMARKS)
            .setClassificationMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
            .build();

    return options;
}

public float getLeftEyeOpenProbability(FirebaseVisionFace face){
    if(face.getLeftEyeOpenProbability() != FirebaseVisionFace.UNCOMPUTED_PROBABILITY && new FaceLandmarksPosition().getLeftEyePosition(face) != null){
        float leftEyeProbability = face.getLeftEyeOpenProbability();
        return leftEyeProbability;
    }

    return -1;
}

public float getRightEyeOpenProbability(FirebaseVisionFace face){
    if(face.getRightEyeOpenProbability() != FirebaseVisionFace.UNCOMPUTED_PROBABILITY && new FaceLandmarksPosition().getLeftEyePosition(face) != null){
        float rightEyeProbability = face.getRightEyeOpenProbability();
        return rightEyeProbability;
    }

    return -1;
}

public float getSmilingProbability(FirebaseVisionFace face){
    if(face.getSmilingProbability() != FirebaseVisionFace.UNCOMPUTED_PROBABILITY){
        float smilingProbability = face.getSmilingProbability();
        return smilingProbability;
    }

    return -1;
}

public int getTrackingId(FirebaseVisionFace face){
    if(face.getTrackingId() != FirebaseVisionFace.INVALID_ID){
        int faceId = face.getTrackingId();
        return faceId;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

}

**FaceLandmarksPosition**

```
 package com.example.progettoesame;

 import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApiNotAvailableException;
 import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.FirebaseVision;
 import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.common.FirebaseVisionPoint;
 import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.face.FirebaseVisionFace;
 import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.face.FirebaseVisionFaceContour;
 import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.face.FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark;

 import java.util.List;


 public class FaceLandmarksPosition {

public float getEulerAngleY(FirebaseVisionFace face){
    return face.getHeadEulerAngleY();
}

public float getEulerAngleZ(FirebaseVisionFace face){
    return face.getHeadEulerAngleZ();
}

public FirebaseVisionPoint getLeftEyePosition(FirebaseVisionFace face){
    FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark leftEye = face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.LEFT_EYE);

    if(leftEye != null){
        FirebaseVisionPoint leftEyePosition = leftEye.getPosition();
        return leftEyePosition;
    }

    return null;
}

public FirebaseVisionPoint getRightEyePosition(FirebaseVisionFace face){
    FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark rightEye = face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.RIGHT_EYE);

    if(rightEye != null){
        FirebaseVisionPoint rightEyePosition = rightEye.getPosition();
        return rightEyePosition;
    }

    return null;
}

List<FirebaseVisionPoint> getLeftEyeContour(FirebaseVisionFace face){
    FirebaseVisionPoint leftEyePosition = getLeftEyePosition(face);

    if(leftEyePosition != null){
        List<FirebaseVisionPoint> leftEyeContour = face.getContour(FirebaseVisionFaceContour.LEFT_EYE).getPoints();
        return leftEyeContour;
    }

    return null;
}

List<FirebaseVisionPoint> getRightEyeContour(FirebaseVisionFace face){
    FirebaseVisionPoint rightEyePosition = getRightEyePosition(face);

    if(rightEyePosition != null){
        List<FirebaseVisionPoint> rightEyeContour = face.getContour(FirebaseVisionFaceContour.RIGHT_EYE).getPoints();
        return rightEyeContour;
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

**Is there any class that will help me draw that contour? I want to start drawing the left and eye right at the moment**

Answer (score 0):

Use Overlay to display the detected face on bitmap

Here is piece of code [taken from the MLKit starter app](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit) demonstrating how to draw your contour

```
/** Draws the face annotations for position on the supplied canvas.  */
override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
    val face = firebaseVisionFace ?: return

    // Draws a circle at the position of the detected face, with the face's track id below.
    val x = translateX(face.boundingBox.centerX().toFloat())
    val y = translateY(face.boundingBox.centerY().toFloat())
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, FACE_POSITION_RADIUS, facePositionPaint)
    canvas.drawText("id: ${face.trackingId}", x + ID_X_OFFSET, y + ID_Y_OFFSET, idPaint)

    // Draws a bounding box around the face.
    val xOffset = scaleX(face.boundingBox.width() / 2.0f)
    val yOffset = scaleY(face.boundingBox.height() / 2.0f)
    val left = x - xOffset
    val top = y - yOffset
    val right = x + xOffset
    val bottom = y + yOffset
    canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, boxPaint)

    val contour = face.getContour(FirebaseVisionFaceContour.ALL_POINTS)
    for (point in contour.points) {
        val px = translateX(point.x)
        val py = translateY(point.y)
        canvas.drawCircle(px, py, FACE_POSITION_RADIUS, facePositionPaint)
    }

    if (face.smilingProbability >= 0) {
        canvas.drawText(
                "happiness: ${String.format("%.2f", face.smilingProbability)}",
                x + ID_X_OFFSET * 3,
                y - ID_Y_OFFSET,
                idPaint)
    }

    if (face.rightEyeOpenProbability >= 0) {
        canvas.drawText(
                "right eye: ${String.format("%.2f", face.rightEyeOpenProbability)}",
                x - ID_X_OFFSET,
                y,
                idPaint)
    }
    if (face.leftEyeOpenProbability >= 0) {
        canvas.drawText(
                "left eye: ${String.format("%.2f", face.leftEyeOpenProbability)}",
                x + ID_X_OFFSET * 6,
                y,
                idPaint)
    }
    val leftEye = face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.LEFT_EYE)
    leftEye?.position?.let {
        canvas.drawCircle(
                translateX(it.x),
                translateY(it.y),
                FACE_POSITION_RADIUS,
                facePositionPaint)
    }
    val rightEye = face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.RIGHT_EYE)
    rightEye?.position?.let {
        canvas.drawCircle(
                translateX(it.x),
                translateY(it.y),
                FACE_POSITION_RADIUS,
                facePositionPaint)
    }
    val leftCheek = face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.LEFT_CHEEK)
    leftCheek?.position?.let {
        canvas.drawCircle(
                translateX(it.x),
                translateY(it.y),
                FACE_POSITION_RADIUS,
                facePositionPaint)
    }

    val rightCheek = face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.RIGHT_CHEEK)
    rightCheek?.position?.let {
        canvas.drawCircle(
                translateX(it.x),
                translateY(it.y),
                FACE_POSITION_RADIUS,
                facePositionPaint)
    }
}
```